Black box appears between chapter title and \minitoc after specific \part{...} command
I'm encountering a puzzling issue in my LaTeX thesis document. I'm using the minitoc package to include mini tables of contents at the beginning of each chapter. However, a black box appears between the chapter title and the \minitoc in the first chapter after a specific \part{...} command.
Details:
The black box only appears after the \part{Framework instantiation} command.
It doesn't happen after other \part{...} commands in my document.
Swapping chapters doesn't resolve the issue—the black box always appears in the first chapter following the \part{Framework instantiation}. So this tells me the content of the chapter is not the problem?
Commenting out the \minitoc command of the affected chapter makes the black box disappear.
Replacing the content with placeholder text (e.g., "Some text here.") does not cause the black box to appear.
What I've Tried:
Added \mtcaddpart after each \part{...} command:
latex
Copy code
\part{Framework instantiation}
\mtcaddpart
Ensured proper placement of \dominitoc and \minitoc:
Placed \dominitoc immediately after \begin{document}.
Placed \minitoc right after each \chapter{...} command.

welcome! you will need to create a minimal example which you can post here for people to reproduce the problem. otherwise, all we know is that something in code we can't see is responsible. you could try looking in the relevant .toc file. does the problem only occur on the second compilation i.e. if you clean the directory of generated files so there are no contents listings, do you get the problem or not?
